# Why doesn't my extension show up in Chrome Web store search result?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made an extension at this link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tripsurfing/nbnnmjfiagkecpgnabklboopccmihnig.

The name of the extension is TripSurfing, but when I search for "trip" on Chrome Web Stoe, it's never shown my extension although I already uploaded all the icons with the same size required by Google.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/trip?_category=extensions.

What is the reason? And how can I fix that?

Comment: Your extension shows up if you search for `TripSurfing` so it is searchable in the store. The reason why you cant see your extension when your search for `trip` its because its a too broad term and other extensions have higher rep for that keyword.

Comment: Even when I scroll down for the whole list, it doesn't show up. And other extension with no "trip" string in its name or fewer "trip" string in the description, and no installation can still show up??? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asphalt10-pc/nejfnkpafnphppnpilhalekckhldjdig

Answer (score 1):

There's a variety of reasons for you extension isn't yet appearing in the Chrome Web Store.

Some of them include:

> Your app manifest is version 1. We have upgraded to manifest version 2, therefore all manifest v1 apps are unlisted. Please upgrade your item to manifest v2.

Or:

> You just published your app. It might take a few hours before we index it.

Or even:

> Your app is not listed in the region you are searching in.

Check the full list [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-listing-09).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! In fact I checked some extensions in the result list https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/trip?_category=extensions, but some are still in version 0.x or 1.x. And when I search for a full name "TripSurfing", it does show up. So I think the reason is not because of v1, v2 or region (it's for all region). But I will still try to upgrade it to v2 then I'll let you know.

Comment: This is the config in my manifest.json: 
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "TripSurfing",
  "description": "Most-used tool for travel-lover!",
  "version": "1.1.6",

You mean "manifest_version" attribute, right? It's already 2.

Comment: I've just searched in Chrome Web Store and your extension is appearing :) Regarding the manifest, everything appears fine

Comment: You searched for "trip" or "tripsurfing"? The problem is only with "trip"

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to basics of search algorithms. You're not significant enough yet for the search for generic term "trip" to pick up your extension.

Your extension is definitely in CWS, and searchable. It's just low in search rankings, as one would expect from a new extension in a saturated "market".

The "whole" list you mention for searching for "trip" is just the top 105 results for this search. It would be naive to think it's the only extensions CWS can find for the term.

There is [no magic bullet for solving it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization). Get popular with other marketing strategies, and then you might become significant enough. Also note that search indexes for such indirect terms take a while to update.

Comment: How do you explain about this one? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trip-alarm/dmfglicjpgfkbpapojgkooefokingmnj or this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tripflock/gegfflmbljpdondhmclfigkmmmlokkfh.
One has 1 user and one has the same number of users like mine. But they're still in the search result for "trip"